# How to create a DAX measure for finding values in a previous month, not using a Date field?

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am currently trying to create a report that shows how customers behave over time, but instead of doing this by date, I am doing it by customer age (number of months since they first became a customer). So using a date field isn't really an option, considering one customer may have started in Dec 2016 and another starts in Jun 2017.

What I'm trying to find is the month-over-month change in units purchased. If I was using a date field, I know that I could use

[Previous Month Total] = CALCULATE(SUM([Total Units]), PREVIOUSMONTH([FiscalDate]))

I also thought about using EARLIER() to find out but I don't think it would work in this case, as it requires row context that I'm not sure I could create. Below is a simplified version of the table that I'll be using.

```
ID    Date     Age Units
219  6/1/2017   0   10
219  7/1/2017   1   5
219  8/1/2017   2   4
219  9/1/2017   3   12
342  12/1/2016  0   500
342  1/1/2017   1   280
342  2/1/2017   2   325
342  3/1/2017   3   200
342  4/1/2017   4   250
342  5/1/2017   5   255
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about something like this?

```
PrevTotal = 
    VAR CurrAge = SELECTEDVALUE(Table3[Age])
    RETURN CALCULATE(SUM(Table3[Units]), ALL(Table3[Date]), Table3[Age] = CurrAge - 1)
```

The `CurrAge` variable gives the `Age` evaluated in the current filter context. You then plug that into a filter in the `CALCULATE` line.

Comment: That did the trick, I was somehow unaware that I could even declare variables in a DAX measure. Thanks for your help!

Comment: They're very useful, especially when you want to use the same value several times.